# C++ change base's member variable and print it from derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

The idea is:

> I've 2 classes, one named `Print` with only one method called `printName`, and other class named `Human` with variable `name`. I want `printName` to print whatever the `name` variable in the `Human` class is.

Example:

```cpp
class Print {
public:
    char name[255];  // name will be overridden from Human class.
    void print() { std::cout << name << std::endl; }  // `this.name` should be from Human class.
};

class Human : public Print {
public:
    char name[255];
};

int main() {
    Human h;
    h.name = "Somename";
    h.print(); // Should outputs: Somename
}
```

Comment: Although it is not too difficult to make this kind of an arrangement, I have to call into question why both classes have a field called `name`. This suggests a more deeper, fundamental design flaw that will likely continue to create other issues, and this desired behavior of `printName`, or `print`, or whatever it's name is, is a symptom of a larger issue. Can you please explain what this is supposed to accomplish, having two different `name`s in a human? P.S. do you know what virtual functions are, and how they work?

Comment: In C++, **member variables** cannot be "overridden", they can only be *shadowed* (which is rarely a good idea, because it is a source of bugs).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My example was just an idea, not real coding. The question is: I've a class that has some methods and variables. I want to change those variables, but keeping its methods doing what they should do BUT WITHT THE NEW VALUE FROM THE VARIABLES. In my post's example, look how I just changed the `name` from Human class and the `printName` just works with the new value.

Comment: Once you have some methods or variables in class you cannot "change" them, by creating a derived class. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @Eljay so that means I can't do it. Is there any `best practice way` about how to do something similar?

Comment: The problem with seeking the "best practice way" of anything is that if you ask ten C++ developers what is the "best practice way" for something, you are guaranteed to get at least eleven completely different answers. C++ offers many features that can be used, in various ways, of accomplishing similar things: virtual methods and inheritance, templates and specialization. Neither one, nor anything else is "best practice". They do different things. They are not a drop-in replacement for each other. One needs to understand what they are, how they work, then make a decision based on that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik   Only 11 answers?   In my experience, if you ask ten C++ developers in a room for opinions, the first stated opinions will spin off rebuttals and other opinions, and so it goes on.   So you get substantially more opinions dropping out than the number of developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions: Curiously Recurring Template Pattern [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp).

```
template <typename T>
class Print {
public:
    char name[255];
    void print() { std::cout << static_cast<T*>(this)->name << std::endl; }
};

class Human : public Print<Human> {
public:
    char name[255];
};

int main() {
    Human h;
    h.name = "Somename";
    h.print(); // Outputs: Somename
}
```

`h.name = "Somename"` will not compile.